# When using tar is there any situation we don't use -f switch?

Tags: tar

Normally I use tar with either `tar -cvzf` to create or to `tar -xvzf` to extract. 
Both cases need `-f` to specify the file. I know sometimes I will supply -f from standard input or standard output, but I still need -f switch.

So is there any situation I do not specify `-f` ?

Comment: Will this work for you: `tar xz < file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `-f` when you use stdin/stdout.

You may for instance do `tar -cv foo > foo.tar`, which will create `foo.tar`.

This may also be used to pipe together commands. Say you want to create a 7z compressed tar file:

```
tar -cv foo/ | 7z a -si foo.tar.7z
```

or you can do remote backups easily

```
tar -cv foo/ | ssh user@example.org "cat > backup.tar"
```

The same may also be applied in reverse

```
ssh user@example.org "cat backup.tar" | tar -xv
```

to extract the tar ball.

So yes, there's cases when you don't need or don't want the f switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode the archive file

```
  $ export TAPE=archive-file
```

This is possible but not recommended

See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/file-tutorial.html#SEC14)